# How to Add Top Tabs inside the bottom tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-top-tabs

Hi I want to Add the top tabs inside the bottom tab page
So I want the screen, instead of the bottom tab header,
I want to show top tabs that can move to the another screen ,

And Here is my Snack Code Screen : https://snack.expo.dev/@aza1200/material-top-tabs-navigator-%7C-react-navigation

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TopTabNavigator = () => {
  <TopTab.Navigator >
    <TopTab.Screen name="Post Room" component={FeedScreen} />
    <TopTab.Screen name="Rooms" component={NotificationsScreen} />
  </TopTab.Navigator>
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Top Tabs will" component={TopTabNavigator} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name="Rooms" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Here is my Code and
It will be very helpful if someone let me know how to fix below codes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Notifications!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TopTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Post Room" component={FeedScreen} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="Rooms" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Top Tabs will" component={TopTabNavigator} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name="Rooms" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

only add return in TopTabNavigator.

Comment: Oh... I was a fooooooooool.... Thanks...