# React Native, Top and Bottom navbar

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, navbar

I created a bottom nav bar then realized I also needed to create a top bar but I keep getting an error about rendering within  and cannot use multiple navigators. I tried using chat gbt I went through reactnative website and could not find the answer. Thank you for everyone's help. all code for my container is listed below

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function TopTabNav() {
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          let rn = route.name;

          if (rn === languageSelector) {
            iconName = focused ? 'Language' : 'language-outline';
          } else if (rn === streak) {
            iconName = focused ? 'Streak' : 'streak-outline';
          } else if (rn === profile) {
            iconName = focused ? 'Profile' : 'profile-outline';
          }

          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
      })}
    >
      <TopTab.Screen name={languageSelector} component={LanguageSelector} />
      <TopTab.Screen name={streak} component={Streak} />
      <TopTab.Screen name={profile} component={Profile} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function MainContainer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>

    <TopTabNav />  /** Top Nav Bar */

      <BottomTab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            let rn = route.name;

            if (rn === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
            } else if (rn === languageName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'book' : 'book-outline'; 
            } else if (rn === addFriendName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'people' : 'people-outline';
            } else if (rn === settingsName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline';
            }

            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'tomato',
          inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
          labelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10 },
          style: { padding: 10, height: 70 }
        }}
      >
        <BottomTab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name={languageName} component={Language} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name={addFriendName} component={AddFriend} />
        <BottomTab.Screen name={settingsName} component={Settings} />
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

``
```

Comment: Is this answering your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74781313/20002061](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74781313/20002061)